# Vim commands for browsing git history of a file

Tags: git, vimscript

I've been working on this mostly for myself until now, but I am now thinking that it might be worth uploading for other people to use. But first I wanted to ask what other people think because I don't do much vimscript and have no idea about the dos and don'ts (aka. best practices) of the language.

Description: A collection of vim commands to navigate through a single files history in a git repository and compare (diff) them to other versions of the same file.

Note about optimizations: Since the external call to git is a huge bottleneck anyway, I don't think it's worth optimizing any of the vimscript code in this example, but suggestions are of course welcome anyway if they are good examples of more general best practices.

Here's the code:

```
function! s:git_history()
    if exists("b:git_history")
        if b:git_history[0]+10 < localtime()
            return b:git_history[1]
        end
    end

    if exists("b:git_original_file")
        let l:fname = b:git_original_file
    else
        let l:fname = expand("%")
    end
    let l:commits = system('git log --format="%h" --follow '.l:fname)
    let l:hist = split(l:commits, "\n")
    let b:git_history = [localtime(), l:hist]

    return l:hist
endfun

function! s:git_first()
    if &modified
        echo "Save your changes first!"
        return
    end
    let l:history = s:git_history()
    call s:file_at_revision(get(l:history, -1, "HEAD"))
endfun

function! s:git_last()
    if &modified
        echo "Save your changes first!"
        return
    end
    let l:history = s:git_history()
    call s:file_at_revision(get(l:history, 1, "HEAD"))
endfun

function! s:git_info()
    if !exists("b:git_revision_hash") || !exists("b:git_original_file")
        echo "Error 01: Not a file@revision buffer!"
        return
    end
    echo system("git show --no-patch ".b:git_revision_hash)
endfun

function! s:git_next()
    if !exists("b:git_revision_hash") || !exists("b:git_original_file")
        echo "Error 01: Not a file@revision buffer!"
        return
    end
    let l:history = s:git_history()
    let l:idx = index(l:history, b:git_revision_hash)
    if l:idx == -1
        echo "Error 02"
        return
    end
    let l:new_revision = get(l:history, l:idx-1, "LAST")
    if l:new_revision=="LAST"
        echo "Already at latest revision! ".l:new_revision
        return
    else
        call s:file_at_revision(l:new_revision)
    end
endfun

function! s:git_prev()
    if !exists("b:git_revision_hash") || !exists("b:git_original_file")
        let l:new_revision = s:git_history()[0]
    else
        let l:history = s:git_history()
        let l:idx = index(l:history, b:git_revision_hash)
        if l:idx == -1
            echo "Error 03: cannot find revision ".b:git_revision_hash
            return
        end
        let l:new_revision = get(l:history, l:idx+1, "FIRST")
    end
    if l:new_revision=="FIRST"
        echo "Already at earliest revision! ".l:new_revision
        return
    else
        call s:file_at_revision(l:new_revision)
    end
endfun

function! s:file_at_revision(rev)
    let l:pos = getpos(".")
    if exists("b:git_original_file")
        let l:fname = b:git_original_file
        let l:ftail = fnamemodify(b:git_original_file, ":t")
    else
        let l:fname = expand("%:t")
        let l:ftail = expand("%:t")
    end
    let l:ftype = &filetype

    ene!
    set modifiable
    silent exec "file ".l:ftail."@".a:rev
    exec "r!git show ".a:rev.":".l:fname
    1,1del
    let l:pos[0] = bufnr('.')
    call setpos('.', l:pos)
    setl nomodifiable
    setl buftype=nofile
    setl bufhidden=delete
    let &filetype = l:ftype

    let b:git_original_file = l:fname
    let b:git_revision_hash = a:rev
    call s:git_info()
endfun

function! s:git_diff(...)
    if a:0
        diffthis
        split
        call s:file_at_revision(a:1)
        au BufUnload <buffer> diffoff!
        diffthis
    else
        if exists("b:git_revision_hash")
            call s:git_diff(get(s:git_history(), index(s:git_history(), b:git_revision_hash)+1, "NIL"))
        else
            call s:git_diff("HEAD")
        end
    end
endfun

command! GitNext call <sid>git_next()
command! GitPrev call <sid>git_prev()
command! GitFirst call <sid>git_first()
command! GitLast call <sid>git_last()
command! GitInfo call <sid>git_info()
command! -nargs=1 GitCheckout call <sid>file_at_revision(<f-args>)
command! -nargs=? GitCompare call <sid>git_diff(<f-args>)
```

Comment: I noticed quite a few smaller mistakes and a huge one: the git history caching is broken because the `<` should be a `>`